# Restore Previous Apex Class version

Tags: apex, community, developer-console

I've accidentally overwritten my apex class.  Is there any way to restore the previous version from 3 days ago?

Thanks,

Comment: Sadly Salesforce doesn't have any built in Version Control, so if you don't have your own seperate VC then you maybe out of luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salesforce only keeps the most currently code that successfully deployed/compiled. If you're using the Force.com IDE, you'll have a history file you can go back to. This defaults to about a week. Just right-click, and choose Replace, and you can choose any recent version you'd like to go back to. In the future, you really should consider a CVS system, such as Git. You can use Git without a server and with minimal expertise, and it works well with the Force.com IDE. Not using a CVS is like driving a car without seat belts, air bags, anti-lock brakes or power steering. You can do it, but it's harder to avoid accidents, and accidents are far more fatal.

Comment: Version control really is a *must have* for professional development. Your analogy is spot on. Except replace a car with a delivery truck loaded with precious artifacts.

Comment: Thank you all.  I had to troubleshoot and finally got it to work again.